# No se puede procesar el archivo

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Descargue Visual studio 2019 y estoy trabajando en proyecto en c#, pero al  poner en el formulario una imagen "icon" y compilar me sale el siguiente error

**Gravedad Código   Descripción Proyecto Archivo Línea Estado suprimido
Error No se puede procesar el archivo Tareas.resx porque está en Internet o en una zona restringida, o bien tiene la marca de la Web. Quite esta marca si desea procesar los archivos.CapaPresentacion**

"pasa con cualquier imagen que ponga en el proyecto y quito la imagen y deja compilar bien"

busque que pasaba y decían que desbloqueara la seguridad de la imagen entre ha las propiedades, desbloquee la seguridad del la imagen elimine el código que genera la imagen en el .resx pero sigue saliendo lo mismo

**no veo como solucionar esto alguna ayuda ¿?**

esto es lo que contiene el archivo Tareas.resx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <!-- 
    Microsoft ResX Schema 

    Version 2.0

    The primary goals of this format is to allow a simple XML format 
    that is mostly human readable. The generation and parsing of the 
    various data types are done through the TypeConverter classes 
    associated with the data types.

    Example:

    ... ado.net/XML headers & schema ...
    <resheader name="resmimetype">text/microsoft-resx</resheader>
    <resheader name="version">2.0</resheader>
    <resheader name="reader">System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, ...</resheader>
    <resheader name="writer">System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, ...</resheader>
    <data name="Name1"><value>this is my long string</value><comment>this is a comment</comment></data>
    <data name="Color1" type="System.Drawing.Color, System.Drawing">Blue</data>
    <data name="Bitmap1" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64">
        <value>[base64 mime encoded serialized .NET Framework object]</value>
    </data>
    <data name="Icon1" type="System.Drawing.Icon, System.Drawing" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64">
        <value>[base64 mime encoded string representing a byte array form of the .NET Framework object]</value>
        <comment>This is a comment</comment>
    </data>

    There are any number of "resheader" rows that contain simple 
    name/value pairs.

    Each data row contains a name, and value. The row also contains a 
    type or mimetype. Type corresponds to a .NET class that support 
    text/value conversion through the TypeConverter architecture. 
    Classes that don't support this are serialized and stored with the 
    mimetype set.

    The mimetype is used for serialized objects, and tells the 
    ResXResourceReader how to depersist the object. This is currently not 
    extensible. For a given mimetype the value must be set accordingly:

    Note - application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64 is the format 
    that the ResXResourceWriter will generate, however the reader can 
    read any of the formats listed below.

    mimetype: application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64
    value   : The object must be serialized with 
            : System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
            : and then encoded with base64 encoding.

    mimetype: application/x-microsoft.net.object.soap.base64
    value   : The object must be serialized with 
            : System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter
            : and then encoded with base64 encoding.

    mimetype: application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64
    value   : The object must be serialized into a byte array 
            : using a System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter
            : and then encoded with base64 encoding.
    -->
  <xsd:schema id="root" xmlns="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" />
    <xsd:element name="root" msdata:IsDataSet="true">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:element name="metadata">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="assembly">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:attribute name="alias" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="data">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
                <xsd:element name="comment" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="3" />
              <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="4" />
              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="resheader">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:choice>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:schema>
  <resheader name="resmimetype">
    <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="version">
    <value>2.0</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="reader">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="writer">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <metadata name="menuStrip1.TrayLocation" type="System.Drawing.Point, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
    <value>17, 17</value>
  </metadata>
  <metadata name="$this.TrayHeight" type="System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
    <value>42</value>
  </metadata>
  <assembly alias="System.Drawing" name="System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  <data name="$this.Icon" type="System.Drawing.Icon, System.Drawing" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64">
    <value>
        AAABAAEAICAAAAEAIACoEAAAFgAAACgAAAAgAAAAQAAAAAEAIAAAAAAAABAAAA4IAAAOCAAAAAAAAAAA
        AAD///8A////AP///wD///8A////AP///wD///8A////AP///wD///8A////AP///wD///8A////AP//
        /wD///8A////AF9fX7JeXl5t////AP///wD///8A////AP///wD///8A////AP///wD///8A////AP//
        /wD///8A////AP///wD///8A////AP///wCovTojpro5P6e7PECnuzxAp7s8QKe7PECnuzxAp7s8QKe7
        PECnuzxAp7s8QKe7PECnuzxAe4JQdmBgYPyUoJ/KrcGkg6m8Y1CnuzxAp7s8QKe7PECpujg7qrg5Ev//
        /wD///8A////AP///wD///8A////AP//AAGnvDlrp7w67ae8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/qLmM/6m7q/+xxNb/r8PT/2Wkof+duEf/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w60Ke+PDf///8A////AP///wD///8Ap7s5l6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+vxGX/x9zs/7HGs/9Unrn/JYzh/zyU
        xP+duEf/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/Km8OET///8A////AKa6OT+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6i9Pv/D2eL/VazH/0Sa
        u/8ljOH/JYzh/zyVw/+duEb/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w64rOzMwr///8Aprw6kKe8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/x9WD/9vkr/+ovT3/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/3Cx
        nP8hnPL/Ipzx/0Sau/8ljOH/JYzh/z2Vwv+duEb/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/pro5P////wCmvDq+p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/qr9C/97mtP/6+/T/9Pfn/9vkr/+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/pLs+/0qmuv8hnPL/Ipzx/0OavP8ljOH/JYzh/z2Vwv+euUb/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDpu////AKe7
        OcinvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov/o7cv/7vLZ/7PFVv+0xlf/+frx/87akv+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w7/8jV
        hf/O2ZH/ztmR/87Zkf/O2ZH/ytiT/1av1P8hnPL/Ipzy/02h0P8ljOH/JYzh/z2Vwv+euUb/p7w6/6i7
        OXj///8Ap7s5yKe8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/7jJYf+pvj//p7w6/6e8Ov+8zGr//P34/8LQdv+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+rv0T/4ei8/+bsx//m7Mf/5uzH/+bsx//m7Mf/4erI/1205f8hnPL/Ipzy/1Kl3f8ljOH/JYzh/z6V
        wf+euUb/qLs5eP///wCnuznIp7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov/H1IL/+/z2/7jJ
        YP+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/pLs+/0qmuv8hnPL/Ipzx/0Oa
        vP8ljOH/OpHF/1dpjf+Zq0mC////AKe7OcinvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov/S3Zv/2OGn/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/pLs+/0qm
        uv8hnPL/Ipzx/0yWr/9FU6H/QEej/0pSmOdATaYUp7s5yKe8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/pLs+/0qmuv85ntP/TmXO/1llkv9AR6P/QEej/0BIo6CnuznIp7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/pLs+/2h/o/9KWtf/SlrW/1llkv9AR6P/QEiih6e7OcinvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/pbo+/2Z4p/9KWtf/SlrW/15rkcNAQL8Ep7s5yKe8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+rv0T/4Oi6//P25P+vwk3/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/pbo+/3eKi/96jYb/pbg9ev//
        /wCnuznIp7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/t8he//L14v/u8tj/5uzI/+3x1/+qv0L/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+7y2b/wM9y/8DPcv/Az3L/wM9y/8DPcv/Az3L/wM9y/8DPcv/Az3L/vs5u/6e8O/+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+ouzl4////AKe7OcinvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov/t8db/2eKp/6m+P/+rv0L/7vLY/+PpwP+nvDv/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/rMBG/+/z2//09+b/9Pfm//T35v/09+b/9Pfm//T35v/09+b/9Pfm//T35v/z9uP/tMZY/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6i7OXj///8Ap7s5yKe8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+ww07/9fjp/9bg
        pP+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/qLs5eP///wCnuznIp7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+3yF7/+/z1/8jVg/+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+ouzl4////AKe7OcinvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov++zW3/yNWD/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6i7OXj///8Ap7s5yKe8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/qLs5eP///wCnuznIp7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+ouzl4////AKe7
        OcinvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/qL08/9Ldm//m7Mj/q79C/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6i7
        OXj///8Ap7s5yKe8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6/CTP/o7cv/9ffp/+7y2f/k6sL/qL08/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/scRQ/7XHWf+1x1n/tcdZ/7XHWf+1x1n/tcdZ/7XHWf+1x1n/tcdZ/7PFVf+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/qLs5eP///wCnuznIp7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/7fHX/+Xrxf+uwUn/r8JL//T35v/Y4af/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/63ARv/5+/P//////////////////////////////////////////////////v79/7XH
        Wv+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+ouzl4////AKe7OcinvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+vwkv/p7w7/6e8Ov+nvDr/tsdb//r7
        9P/L14r/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6m9Pv+qvkD/qr5A/6q+QP+qvkD/qr5A/6q+QP+qvkD/qr5A/6q+
        QP+pvj//p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6i7OXj///8Ap7s5yKe8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/v85w//z9+f+/zm//p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/qLs5eP///wCnvDq0p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/yNWF/9Hcl/+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+mvTtk////AKe8O4KnvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6i9ODL///8Apbw8Iqe8
        OfSnvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDrCgIAAAv//
        /wD///8Ap706Xae8OvmnvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w64Ke/
        OCD///8A////AP///wD///8Aprw3Lqe9Oa2nvDrjp7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8
        Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr/p7w6/6e8Ov+nvDr7qLw60qa8
        OpCktjcO////AP///wD///8A//+f//AAAB+AAAAHgAAAAwAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAA
        AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABAAAAAQAA
        AAEAAAABAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABgAAAA8AAAAc=
</value>
  </data>
</root>
```

Comment: Sucedió algo similar al usar una copia de respaldo en la nube. Cambiar propiedades, desbloquear; nada daba resultado.
Noté que tampoco podía renombrar la carpeta. A este punto el desbloqueo total lo obtuve al reiniciar la computadora.

Answer (score 0):

La imagen la debes asignar a la propiedad `Image` de un control `PictureBox`, no se como lo estas realizando pero esta raro que se corrompa el `resx` asignado al form.

Agregas el Picturebox al form y buscas la propiedad `Imagen`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seleccion la imagen que quieres visualizar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cual se agregara en el `resx`

Comment: No me deja, agrego cualquier imagen y me sale lo mismo sea picturebox sea que ponga un .ico  no me deja compilar.

Comment: si quitas todo, no agregues nada y compilas, lo hace sin error ?

Comment: Si señor, si quito la imagen compila correctamente si la pongo sea cual sea la forma que agrego una imagen me sale ese error.

Comment: pones la imagen usando la propiedad de un picturebox, podrias ver de usar alguna otra imagen diferente

Comment: Ya lo solucione poniendo la imagen dentro del proyecto cree una carpeta dentro del proyecto puse las imágenes y funciono gracias